# redirect traffic on Red Hat

Tags: iptables

I need iptable rules to redirect traffic to interface eth0, port 3306 to another machine on port 3306

Internet (Request on port 3306) ----> HOSTS_A eth0  -----> HOST_B:3306

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like this:

```
# echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp –dport 3306 \
     -j DNAT –to-destination ip_of_destination_machine
# iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -p tcp -d ip_of_destination_machine \
     –dport 3360 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I'm using telnet to test it, # telent HOST_A 3306 but it doesn't connect, is telent a good way of testing port redirection ?

Comment: Depends if something is listening on destination machine on that port. First try to connect with telnet to host_b 3306 to see if it works.

Comment: yes, if I do telnet to HOST_B it connects, port is open on HOST_B iptables, but telnet to HOST_A is timing out.